# Facebook share audio - Cover image not showing

Tags: facebook

I'm testing Facebook audio share functionality and having an issue with the image not showing up.

So this is what I have.

```
<meta name="description" content="audio_description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://domain.com/image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:audio" content="http://domain.com/audio.mp3" />
```

The audio does show up, so that part is fine.
However, the image that is supposed to go on the left of the audio doesn't.
Do I need to do something special?

I also tried

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://domain.com/image.jpg" />
```

Same result.

I'm expecting the output to look something like this http://www.allfacebook.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/share-song.jpg

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: hi have you got success audio sharing on facebook..

Comment: What does the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say when you enter the URL?  If you include the URL, we can view/debug it.